# Scanned PDF inclusion problem with XeTeX driver

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf, pdfpages

I have this specific problem about inclusion of my scanned PDF pages with existing LaTeX document.

I use an iPad application [Scanner Pro](https://readdle.com//) to scan and create PDF copies of my hand-written notes. Then I would use `pdfpages` package to merge these PDFs with my LaTeX document.

So I added something like this in my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
...
\includepdf[pages=-]{scanned_file.pdf}
```

By several attempts, I discovered this oddity that

- if the `.tex` file was ran through `xelatex`, the scanned pdf file refused to be inserted, instead it simply left with as many blank pages as the original scanned file;
- if the `.tex` file was ran through `pdflatex`, the scanned pdf file would be inserted as expected.

Furthermore, I think that this is a problem relating to `graphicx` or `graphics` package, because the same behavior has been found when I tried to use `\includegraphics` command instead of `pdfpages` package to insert these stubborn PDF files.

I also tried explicitly setting driver option of `graphicx` to be `xetex` with no luck.

Here is (one of) my stubborn scanned PDF [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ne0n2t4b8w692vo/Math_Scan%20Aug%204%2C%202014%2C%204.10%20PM.pdf), (It's on Dropbox, and it's written in Chinese...) providing for your test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the XREF table of the provided PDF appears to be broken. You can repair it with pdftk: `pdftk broken.pdf output repaired.pdf`

Comment: @DG' Thanks, It worked. Maybe you should consider submit your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fault in the XREF-table of your PDF seems to be responsible for the problems with `XeTeX`. You can repair your PDFs with a tool like [`pdftk`](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk):

```
pdftk broken.pdf output repaired.pdf
```